# How to import SSH key into Poderosa

Tags: ssh

I have a private SSH key that I have generated using `ssh-keygen` and then imported into PuTTY. This worked fine, but now I want to use the same key in [Poderosa](http://en.poderosa.org/), which seems to use yet another format. Is there a way to use my key there or do I have to create a new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poderosa uses the *ssh.com* private key format, which PuTTYgen can export:

*Conversions* - *Export ssh.com key*